# Página Angular composta de vários componentes

Tags: angular, component

Ao trabalhar com projetos Angular a utilização de `componentes` trás diversos benefícios, porém, esses benefícios podem te levar a cometer alguns erros, que talvez somente serão vistos algumas linhas de código depois.

Seria correto, a criação de uma página composta por vários componentes? ou, a essência do componente está vinculada a funcionalidade e a reutilização de trechos de código?

Exemplo: cursos.component.html:

```
<app-level-one></app-level-one>
<app-level-two></app-level-two>
<app-level-three></app-level-three>
<app-level-four></app-level-four>
<app-level-five></app-level-five>
```

Como pode ser visto, a página acima é composta de outros 5 componentes, neste exemplo os componentes acima não trazem nenhuma funcionalidade diferente, apenas encapsulam um trecho de código `html`e `css`.

Afinal, estaria certo essa abordagem? ou neste caso, onde não existe nenhuma funcionalidade especial e nem a reutilização de trechos de códigos, apenas o encapsulamento de `html` e `css`, deveriamos ter um único componente?

Answer (score 1):

As informações a baixo são do [style guide oficial](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) e da minha experiencia mas no geral em relação a arquitetura de componentes depende muito da aplicação também e apesar de boas práticas não existe bala de prata.

Segundo o stule guide deveria ser seguido o single responsability principle ou seja cada componente deveria se preocupar somente com uma coisa. Isso é relativo mas te da uma ideia de como separar seus componentes. Mas no geral acho que quanto mais componentes vc dividir melhor.

O jeito que eu gosto de fazer é ter componentes baixo nivel num shared -> botões, inputs etc...

Dentro das minhas features ter componentes containers que tenham a logica tipo pegar dados do BE etc...

E depois passar esse dados a componentes de blocos que só exibem esses dados e emitem eventos. seguindo o padrão de smart e dumb components que vc encontra muita coisa na internet.